# How to use the return value from a dynamic_cast on references properly?

Tags: c++, reference, dynamic-cast

We use `dynamic_cast` operator to safely convert a pointer or a reference to a base type into a pointer or a reference to a derived type.

```
    struct Foo{
    void f() const{
        std::cout << "Foo::f()\n";
    }
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
};

struct Bar : Foo{
    void f() const {
        std::cout << "Bar::f()\n";
    }
};

int main(){

    Foo* pf = new Foo{};
    Bar* pb = dynamic_cast<Bar*>(pf);
    if(pb)
        pb->f();
    delete pf;

    pf = new Bar{};
    pb = dynamic_cast<Bar*>(pf);
    if(pb)
        pb->f();
    delete pf;

    Bar b{};
    Foo& rf = b;
    Bar& rb = dynamic_cast<Bar&>(rf);

    // if(rb) // ?
        rb.f();
}
```

- So how to check whether `dynamic_cast` returns a valid or invalid reference? - For a pointer it is OK as long as we compare the pointer against `nullptr` value but for a reference how?

Comment: A failed dynamic cast for a reference throws a `bad_cast` exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Intended as a placeholder for the comment by @1201ProgramAlarm.**

Simply put,

> A failed dynamic cast for a reference throws an exception. – 1201ProgramAlarm

From the [IBM docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=operator-dynamic-casts-references):

> You cannot verify the success of a dynamic cast using reference types by comparing the result (the reference that results from the dynamic cast) with zero because there is no such thing as a zero reference. A failing dynamic cast to a reference type throws a bad_cast exception.

So to verify the cast succeeded, just make sure it didn't throw an exception.